# Extract numeric value from an alphanumeric string without using any predefined function

Tags: java, php, c++, .net, c

I have a variable

```
$string  = "(123) 011 - 34343678";
```

and I want **12301134343678** as an output in integer data type.
How can I do this without using any predefined function in PHP or in any other programming language.

Comment: *Why?* Simple why? PHP gives you the tools to do this and why don't you want to use them?

Comment: @ Rizier123 Yes. I can use them but this question was asked in the interview.

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam Have you tired anything, started with some code?

Comment: think about it if you code your self also, definitely somewhere you goona use some predefined functions of php.

Comment: @ Rizier123 No idea how to start such question because it requires no predefined function

Comment: Can you clarify whether it is ok to provide a solution in a language other than PHP? The question is ambiguous

Comment: @ samgak yes. it is ok to provide a solution in any language because I want logic basically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's not the nicest solution, but something like this could work for you:

Here I simply loop through all characters and check if they are still the same when you cast them to an integer and then back to a string. If yes it is a number otherwise not.

```
<?php

    function own_strlen($str) {
        $count = 0;
        while(@$str[$count] != "")
            $count++;
        return $count;
    }

    function removeNonNumericalCharacters($str) {
        $result = "";

        for($count = 0; $count < own_strlen($str); $count++) {
            $character = $str[$count];
            if((string)(int)$str[$count] === $character)
                $result .= $str[$count];
        }

        return $result;

    }

    $string  = "(123) 011 - 34343678";
    echo removeNonNumericalCharacters($string);

?>
```

output:

```
12301134343678
```

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I don't love the error control operator `@` in the code. Trying to get rid of it

Comment: `((string)(int)$str[$count] === $character)` this is the key! We can be sure to get a number from a character in a string that is a number xD Nicely done Rizier.

Comment: Btw, [here's Rizier code ideoned - online execution and output](http://ideone.com/AIlQaW).

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```
<?php
$str =  "15as55 - (011)";

$num_array = array();
for($i = 0;$i<=9;$i++)
{
$num_array[]=$i;    
}


for($coun_str = 0 ; isset($str[$coun_str]) && ($str[$coun_str] != "")  ; )
{
$coun_str++;    
}

$strlen = $coun_str - 1;


$outstr = "";
for($j=0;$j<=$strlen;$j++)
{

    foreach($num_array as $val)
    {
        if((string)$val == $str[$j])
        {
            $outstr .= $str[$j]; 


        }
    }




}
echo $outstr
?>
```

output : 
**1555011**

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.